# CF7 Remove Comma from 'select' 'radio' and 'checkbox' outouts

Tags: functions, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a few 'select' 'radio' and 'checkbox' options on my CF7 form where the user can choose multiple options .. however on the output there is a comma between each item but I want to **remove** this comma so instead of the output being "apples, oranges, pears" it should be "apples oranges pears" - no comma between the items.

Contact Form 7 sent me a link to a very unhelpful guide and have since refused to reply for clarification on how to remove the comma with the select, radio and checkbox inputs.

So can anyone on here help me with the correct function to use for what I need to happen ?

This is the code cf7 suggested but it appear to only add a comma to numeric outputs only and not remove commas from select, radio and checkbox inputs

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced',

  function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
    if ( 'your-number' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
      if ( is_numeric( $submitted ) ) {
        $replaced = number_format( $submitted );
      }
    }

    return $replaced;
 },

 10, 4
);
```

I am a beginner coder and learning by doing but need guidance on this one. How do I change the above code to **remove** the comma from 'select' 'radio' and 'checkbox' outputs ?

Tried to find a way to change the above code myself but it fails in the function file.

Original Guide from CF7 https://contactform7.com/2019/12/08/customizing-mail-tag-replacement/

Thanks

Comment: I believe CF7 is only run by one person, so it may be hard to get a hold of them as it is a very popular plugin and there's only so much they can do. However, it is still the best place to get support about plugin-specific topics, as questions about third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @YourManDan .. Unfortunately their one man band support ignored the basis of my question and gave an stock response which didn't actually answer it, in fact made it worse, and have since ignored my requests for clarification. Was hoping to get some assistance from the coding community as im sure someone has found a solution to this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is working, at least you are seeing a result. Working from there it is good to understand what is happening.

1. The function is filtering the mail tags by field name and matching only "your-number". For any other tags, you would need to add further matches.
2. The work is being done on the value submitted by the user using a built in PHP function: number_format(). This will format a number using its defaults, google the function for its usage.

What you really want to do is just replace commas in the submitted value using str_replace instead of number_format BUT.. the submitted value of these types of fields is an array, so str_replace wont work.

Here is an updated and tested solution:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced', 
 
  function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
      
    //   only use a specific field
    if ( 'your-fruit' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
        
        // create a string from the $submitted array    
        $new_string = implode(',',  $submitted);
        
        // now replace the commas in the new string
        $replaced = str_replace(',',' ', $new_string );
        
    }
 
    // return the updated field 
    return $replaced;
  },
 
  10, 4
);
```

Comment: Thanks Laurance for your reply, much appreciated. However when I use the str_replace is get - syntax error, unexpected token "," on line on line 478, which is the  

},

 10,  4
);  part  ... do you know how to fix that part. Also I couldn't find a replacement on google for the number_format to work with text based checkbox or select arrays

Comment: Hi Tom, please edit your question and add the complete code and paste in the link to the guide as well; this function filters the output of the plugin using another line of code. The exact code you have is part of something else and should end after the return statement's closing curly bracket.

Comment: Have added the CF7 guide but the only code it has in is the one I posted above. Thanks

Comment: Hey Tom, I have updated my answer above. Copy this full piece of code into your themes functions.php file.